# Constructing a quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

So basically I have been assigned a question that involves constructing a quadratic equation from scratch and graphing it. So here are the details.

We are designing a water arc fountain, and it has a maximum of $20$ feet wide and taller than $6$ feet and shorter than $50$ feet. We are first asked to place it in a first quadrant graph and have the surface of the pool correspond to the x-axis with the left side at the origin. Using the equation $y = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$, where $(x_1, 0)$, $(x_2, 0)$ are the $x$ intercepts of the parabola, we have to choose a value of $a$ that will produce a reasonable arc. Then we have to convert the equation to the form $y = ax^2+bx+c$. Also, how high will the water arc be if we move the beginning point $1$ foot to the right.

I know that this question might be a piece of cake to do, but I just couldn't wrap my head around it. Would greatly appreciate an answer ASAP.

Comment: Does this mean $x_1=0$ and $x_2=20$? You say the pool is $20$ feet wide but it is unclear whether the water is supposed to arc all the way from one edge to the other or somewhere inside the pool.

Comment: I'm sorry, it has a maximum of 20 feet, not 20 feet. This was a mistake from my side.

Comment: So $x_1=1$, $x_2=19$ would be OK? Or even $x_1=5$, $x_2=15$?

Comment: The water arc should start from origin. God what is wrong with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** The highest point on the parabola is halfway between $x_1$ and $x_2$
(the two $x$-intercepts).
This is a property of any parabola of the form $y = ax^2+bx+c$ (provided
that the parabola has two $x$-intercepts, of course).

Because of this fact, once you have chosen a suitable $x_1$ and $x_2$,
you can select $x$ halfway between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and evaluate 
$y = a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ there.
The result will still have a factor of $a$ in it because you haven't yet
decided what $a$ should be, but now it should not be so hard to find a suitable $a$
so that when you substitute that value, the maximum $y$ is between $6$ and $50$
as desired.

Comment: So for example if I chose x1=0 and x2=10, would -1 be a reasonable value for a?

Comment: It seems to fit within your requirements.